# CreateProcessA %appdata%

Tags: c, windows, appdata

I am trying to use `CreateProcessA` to call an application under the `%appdata%` directory.

For example, using the following:

```
CreateProcessA(
    NULL, "%appdata%\myfile.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &sI, &pI
);
```

Do I need to use the complete path when calling `myfile.exe`or is there someway I can use `%appdata%` in the call to `CreateProcessA`?

Comment: Have a look at [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings(A|W)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), and since you're passing `NULL` to `CreateProcessA` as a first argument, `CreateProcessA`'s 2nd argument : `lpApplicationName` is playing the role of the command line to be executed. Unless `lpApplicationName` points to an exe in a directory, the system will look for it in the following order

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The current directory for the parent process.
> 3. The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory
>          function to get the path of this directory
> 4. The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that
>          obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of
>          this directory is System. The Windows directory. Use the
>          GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.
>          Note that this function does not search the per-application path
>          specified by the App Paths registry key. To include this
>          per-application path in the search sequence, use the ShellExecute
>          function.

Therefore, unless the second argument of `CreateProcessA` is in the form `{directory}/{executable_name}.{ext}`, you'll have to either :

1. Place executable_name in the same directory from which the application loaded
2. Place executable_name in the same directory of the parent process
3. Place executable_name in the Windows System32 directory : C:\Windows\System32
4. Place executable_name in the Windows directory : C:\Windows
5. Include the directory where executable_name is in the PATH

As stated by Ben, take a look at [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265(v=vs.85).aspx) to modify PATH env variable.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in `CreateProcess` should be a writable buffer. If your executable path does not include command line arguments then put the executable path in the first parameter, and leave the second parameter `NULL`

For Windows Vista and above use `SHGetKnownFolderPath`

`FOLDERID_LocalAppData` returns `"c:\\users\\username\\AppData\\Local"`
`FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` returns `"c:\\users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming"`

`ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%", ...)` returns same as `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData`

You should use Unicode unless you are confident that username is ANSI compatible.

```
wchar_t *ptr;
if(S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, NULL, &ptr))
{
    //or FOLDERID_LocalAppData
    std::wstring path = ptr;
    CoTaskMemFree(ptr);

    STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    path += L"\\myfile.exe";
    CreateProcessW(NULL, &path[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
            CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}
```